# Make a loop into a multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Supposing I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [NorthAmerica] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [country] => Canada
                    [capital] => Ottawa
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [country] => USA
                    [capital] => Washington
                )
        )
)
```

How can I loop into it to get `NorthAmerica` and `capital` ?

What I tried:

```
foreach($newDatas as $parent => $value) {
    echo $value; // should return NorthAmerica
    foreach($parent as $values) {
        echo $values['capital']; // should return Ottawa
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing the key and the value. Try:

```
foreach($newDatas as $parent => $value) {
    echo $parent; // should return NorthAmerica
    foreach($value as $values) {
        echo $values['capital']; // should return Ottawa
    }
}
```